# Gatsby .env.production variables - undefined

Tags: environment-variables, gatsby

When building a Gatsby project I'm getting all `env` variables `undefined` in `production` environment.
In `development` everything is fine.
I have 2 similar `.env.development` and `.env.production` files.

In my `gatsby-config.js` I have

```
require('dotenv').config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});
```

and if I `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` during `gatsby build` it gives `production` and the variables can be accessed and logged out.
But later in code something like

```
return request.post(`${process.env.GEOCODING_CF_URL}/latlng`, {...});
```

gives request to `http://localhost:9000/ru/undefined/latlng`.

What am I doing wrong and how this issue can be fixed?

UPDATE:

When I run `gatsby build` - `process.env.NODE_ENV` is `production`

When I run `gatsby serve` - `process.env.NODE_ENV` is `undefined`

If this can help in any way.

Comment: Gatsby has official documentation (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#defining-environment-variables) about using environment variables. Did you read through this?

Comment: Dit you define your environment variable in your env.development and env.production file? GEOCODING_CF_URL=something

Answer (score 3):

If you use environment variables in node you don't need a prefix (like in your gatsby-config.js). However, if you need to use them in a component or a page you must add `GATSBY_` as a prefix, so GEOCODING_CF_URL should be GATSBY_GEOCODING_CF_URL

Answer (score 0):

For me, `NODE_ENV=production yarn gatsby serve` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/

#### Accessing Environment Variables in the browser.

By default, environment variables are only available in Node.js code and are not available in the browser as some variables should be kept secret and not exposed to anyone visiting the site.

To expose a variable in the browser, **you must preface its name with GATSBY_.** So GATSBY_API_URL will be available in browser code but API_KEY will not.

Variables are set when JavaScript is compiled so when the development server is started or you build your site.

```
src/pages/index.js
Copysrc/pages/index.js: copy code to clipboard
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState()
  useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await fetch(
      `${process.env.GATSBY_API_URL}/users`
    ).then(res => res.json())
    setData(result.data)
  })
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(user => (
        <li key={user.id}>
          <a href={user.url}>{user.name}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
export default App
```